# Grails and AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Custom NGINX Configuration Not Working

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, grails

I'm trying to add a custom configuration to NGINX for my Grails 3 application running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I have created the following structure in src/main/resources:

```
.platform/
--| nginx/
----| conf.d/
------ my_custom_config.conf
```

That adds the folders and file to the WEB-INF\classes directory of my '.war'.

According to the Amazon documentation, this should add my file to /etc/nginx/conf.d since I'm using Amazon Linux 2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html

However, the file is not being added, and my additional configurations are being lost.

Using: Tomcat 8.5 with Corretto 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/4.3.9

Does anyone know what might be happening? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I've recently faced the same issue, and written a little set of notes, in my case it's slightly different I was also using codepipeline to perform the build as a Jar before deployment,  maybe it will help someday: 

https://tucanoo.com/grails-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk-build-pipeline-with-nginx-customization/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.platform` should be in the **root** of your zip archive that you upload to EBS, not inside `src/main/resources`.

Comment: Indeed, this solves the problem. By adding it to src/main/webapp, the file goes to the root and gets included. I don't understand why .ebextensions works in src/main/resources while .platform does not.